# How to delete all files and folder in php with permission?

Tags: php, file, permissions, directory, delete-file

I try to delete everything in folder (including subfolders) but:

> Warning: unlink(./../kaj-content/theme/one-four): Permission denied in
>   C:\wamp\www\kaj\kaj-admin\includes\incAppearance.php on line 36

this is my code:

```
$themeDirectory = './../kaj-content/theme';
$dir = $themeDirectory . '/' . $themeName;
array_map('unlink', glob($dir));
```

how can I change my code ?

Other code didn't work, like:

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            $files = scandir($dir);
            foreach ($files as $file)
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
                    rrmdir("$dir/$file");
            rmdir($dir);
        } else if (file_exists($dir))
            unlink($dir);
    }
```

Comment: Anyone can answer my question ?

Answer (score 1):

Your php code is running as a particular user, maybe apache.
Your error means that php does not have the correct permissions for directory one-four.

Check the permissions on that directory. Grant write permission for that directory to the user that php is using. Then, your code will be able to delete the file.